# Dataframe to resample an unbalanced dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling

The [Glass Identification Database](https://datahub.io/machine-learning/glass/r/glass.csv) is an unbalanced dataset and I want to do some resampling.

There are 214 rows data of 5 types of glass. Each type has different number of rows. With below I want to perform random under-sampling, bringing all types to the smallest number (i.e. each type to have 9 rows only.)

```
import pandas

dataset = pandas.read_csv("C:\\temp\\glass.csv"]), sep = ",")

dataset['Type'] = pandas.Categorical(dataset['Type']).codes

# Class count
count_class_0, count_class_1, count_class_2, count_class_3, count_class_4, count_class_5 = dataset.Type.value_counts()

# Divide by class
df_class_0 = dataset[dataset['Type'] == 0]
df_class_1 = dataset[dataset['Type'] == 1]
df_class_2 = dataset[dataset['Type'] == 2]
df_class_3 = dataset[dataset['Type'] == 3]
df_class_4 = dataset[dataset['Type'] == 4]
df_class_5 = dataset[dataset['Type'] == 5]

class_count = dataset.Type.value_counts()
print('Class 0:', class_count[0]) # 70
print('Class 1:', class_count[1]) # 76
print('Class 2:', class_count[2]) # 13
print('Class 3:', class_count[3]) # 29
print('Class 4:', class_count[4]) # 9
print('Class 5:', class_count[5]) # 17

# Random under-sampling
df_class_0_under = df_class_0.sample(count_class_4)
df_test_under = pandas.concat([df_class_0_under, df_class_4], axis=0)

print('Random under-sampling:')
print(df_test_under.Type.value_counts())
```

It shows it wasn't correctly done:

```
Random under-sampling:
0    13
4     9
```

What's the right way to get it done? (bringing all types to the smallest number, i.e. each type to have 9 rows only.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) with minimal of counts of `Type` column:

```
dataset1 = dataset.groupby('Type').head(dataset.Type.value_counts().min())
```

For sampling use lambda function:

```
dataset1 = dataset.groupby('Type').apply(lambda x: x.sample(dataset.Type.value_counts().min()))
```

Comment: sir, thank you! your lambda function is a perfect solution of random under-sampling!

Comment: on the contrary, when I tried "dataset = dataset.groupby('Type').apply(lambda x: x.sample(dataset.Type.value_counts().max()))", it seems not the right way. Can you please advise? thank you.

Comment: @MarkK - Question is if need know what is right way - then better is ask to [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). My answer show how is possible do it, but not idea if correct solution.

Comment: A good practice would be to keep unchanged the raw dataset :)

Answer (score 1):

First, I calculate the `min_count_type`, i.e 9:

`min_count_type = dataset.Type.value_counts().min() -> 9`

Then, I get the list of all different type of glass:

`glass_types = list(dataset.Type.unique())`

And I filter the dataset on the type, and sample only 9 rows of it. Store this subdataframe in a list, and then concatenate all subdataframes:

```
subdatasets = list()
for glass_type in glass_types :
    dataset_glass_type = dataset[dataset['Type']==glass_type]
    dataset_glass_type = dataset_glass_type.sample(min_count_type)
    subdatasets.append(dataset_glass_type)
dataset_undersampled = pd.concat(subdatasets) -> What you want !
```

Comment: If you want to randomize your final dataset, juste use `dataset_undersampled.sample(frac=1)` ;)